# How to make a player appear on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, soundcloud, tumblr

I have a soundcloud player embedded in my html and i have it in a fixed position at the bottom of screen and set to disappear after 10 secs. im trying to make the player reappear when the mouse hovers over the bottom of the screen (as if there's a invisible div fixed to the screen) But this is not working. How can i make the player reappear on a mouse hover of the bottom of the screen?

```html
<!-- section to hover over to make Player visible -->

<div class="hover" align="center" id=‘a’ style="color:#3498db">
<style>   
div.hover{
    position: fixed;
    height: 1000px;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    ;
}

#b {
    display: none;
}

#content:hover~#b{
    display: block;
}
</style>
</div> 
<!-- Soundcloud player and view code -->
<div class="fixed" align="center" id='b'>
<!--Player -->
<iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/playlists/11450645&amp;color=ff5500&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"></iframe>

<!-- fixed position code -->
<style>
div.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    ;
}
<!-- Player hides after x seconds -->
div.fixed {
    -webkit-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 10s forwards;
    -moz-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 10s forwards;
    -o-animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 10s forwards;
    animation: cssAnimation 0s ease-in 10s forwards;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes cssAnimation {
    from {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes cssAnimation {
    from {
        visibility:hidden;
    }
    to {
        width:0;
        height:0;
        visibility:hidden;
    }
}


</style>  
    
<!-- End of Soundcloud code -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do what you said...

## HTML

```
<div id="invisible"></div>
<div id="music-player"></div>
```

## CSS

```
#invisible {
  width: 100vw;
  height: however-tall-or-small-you-want-it-to-be;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100%);
  opacity: 0;
}

#music-player {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

## JS

```
  var i = document.getElementById('invisible');
  var p = document.getElementById('music-player');
  i.addEventListener('mouseenter', showMusicPlayer);
  function showMusicPlayer(){
    p.style.opacity = '1';
  }
```

You could also simply use JS cursor coordinates, and write a function that will determine the particular coordinates of the boundary you desire, and display the music player when the cursor falls within those boundaries.